# Uncaught Invariant Violation: DetailPage.render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting the following Error

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: DetailPage.render(): A valid React
>   element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined,
>   an array or some other invalid object.

```
      import React from 'react';
      import DetailPage from './detail-page.jsx';

      RenderPageComponents() {
            debugger
            switch (this.state.consultantListPage) {
                case 'user-list':
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h1>User List</h1>
                            <ConsultantList
                                ViewDetail={this.ViewDetail.bind(this) }
                                userList={this.state.userList}
                                consultantListPage={this.state.consultantListPage}
                                />
                        </div>);

                case 'user-detail':
                    return (
                         <div>
                           <DetailPage/>
                        </div>
                    );


                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Any help in solving this issue is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove default block from switch case. Now it's working

Answer (score 2):

In default step you must return null

```
default:
return null;
```

Comment: still i am facing same problem

Comment: @user2589387 In that case the problem must lie in a child component. Check `ConsultantList` and `DetailPage` and make sure that they explicitly return `null` if they have nothing to render.